# The Image Magic font does not apply

Tags: reactjs, shell, imagemagick

In my project, I draw a certificate using the shell, on the background image I put all 3 lines. I manage to apply different colors to them, font size, but I can't use different fonts.

```
shell.exec(
    `convert ${certificateImage} -resize 800x600 \
     -gravity south \
     -fill blue -font Candice -pointsize 60 -annotate +0+190 '${certificateHeader}' \
     -fill black -font Candice -pointsize 40 -annotate +0+190 '${certificateTxt}' \
     -fill red -font SheerBeauty -pointsize 20 -annotate -100+40 '${nextCertNumber}' \
     ${thumbnailsFolder}/${certificateId}.png`,
     {async: true},
     () => log('thumbnail created successfully'),
);
```

What am I doing wrong? I would be grateful for any answer. I watched [imagemagic](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/), but so far nothing is working.

Comment: Are the fonts installed on the system? You can run `identify -list Font` to list which fonts would be available to use.

Comment: Perhaps all the fonts are not listed in your type.xml file. If so, then just access them with -font path_to/fontname.ttf.  You can manually list all fonts on your system in the type.xml file. See https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php. Or you can use imagick_type_gen script at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/ to do the search and  install automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I already found, really the problem was exactly that